# for all $a\in \mathbb{R} $ Finding a basis for the column and row space

Tags: linear-algebra

i need to find the basis for the row and column space of A for all $a\in  \mathbb{R} $,

A=$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
        a^2 & a & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & a^2-a & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

as i understand i need to reduce to row echelon, but after i reduce the second row i get
$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
        0 & -2a^2+a & -2a^2 & 2-a^2 \\
        0 & 0 & a^2-a & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

and i can't move the second row to leading 1s, without multiplying by $1/(-2a^2+a)$ where $(-2a^2+a)$ might be zero.

so what should i do ? 
do i need to sperate to two cases :
one where $(-2a^2+a)=0 ->a(-2a+1)=0 ->a1=1/2 ,a2=0$

and one where $(-2a^2+a)\neq0$ and then i can multiply by $1/(-2a^2+a)$?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to split into those two cases—nicely reasoned!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
A & =\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
    a^2       & a & 0 & 2 \\
    0       & 0 & a^2-a & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\\ & \sim \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
    0     & a-2a^2 & 2a^2 & 2-a^2 \\
    0       & 0 & a^2-a & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

If $a=0$, then

\begin{align}
A & \sim\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
    0     & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\\ & \sim \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
    0     & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Since we have pivots in the first and last column, the basis for $\mathrm{col}{A}$ is

$$\{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    2
\end{bmatrix}\}$$

And the basis $\mathrm{row}A$ is

$$\{(1, 2, -2, 1), (0, 0, 0, 2)\}$$

If we suppose now that $a\ne 0$, then we may have different pivot columns depending on $a$.

The next case to consider is $a-2a^2=0\iff a(1-2a) = 0\iff a = \frac{1}{2}$, since $a\ne 0$.

\begin{align}
A & \sim \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
    0     & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{7}{4} \\
    0       & 0 & -\frac{1}{4} & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\\ & \sim \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
    0     & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{7}{4} \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & \frac{23}{8}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

In this case there are pivots in the first, third and fourth row. So the basis for $\mathrm{col}{A}$ is

$$\{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    \frac{1}{4} \\
    0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 \\
    0 \\
    -\frac{1}{4}
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    2
\end{bmatrix}\}$$

And in this case the basis for $\mathrm{row}A$ is

$$\{(1, 2, -2, 1), (0,0,\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{7}{4}),(0,0,0,\tfrac{23}{8})\}$$

Next, we check the cases when $a^2-a=0\iff a(a-1) = 0 \iff a=1$, since, $a\ne 0$.

\begin{align}
A & \sim \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 & -2 & 1 \\
    0     & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

In this case, we have pivots in the first, second, and fourth columns. So the basis for $\mathrm{col}{A}$ is

$$\{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\
    1 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    2
\end{bmatrix}\}$$

And in this case the basis for $\mathrm{row}A$ is

$$\{(1, 2, -2, 1), (0,-1,2,1),(0,0,0,2)\}$$

Finally, in the general case when $a\notin \{0,\tfrac{1}{2},1\}$, we have pivots in the first, second, and third columns. Hence, the basis for $\mathrm{col}{A}$ is

$$\{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    a^2 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\
    a \\
    0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 \\
    0 \\
    a^2-a
\end{bmatrix}\}$$

and the basis for $\mathrm{row}A$ is

$$\{(1,2,-2,1),(0,a-2a^2,2a^2,2-a^2),(0,0,a^2-a,2)\}$$

So you can see that in the case where $a=0$, $\mathrm{rank}{A}$ is different from the other cases. Therefore there is no single basis for every $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, even when $\mathrm{rank}{A} = 3$ it is easily verified that the subspaces of $\mathrm{row}A$ differ depending on the value of $a$. That is the subspace generated by the basis of $\mathrm{row}A$ when $a=\tfrac{1}{2}$ is different from when $a=1$.